# jQuery dropdown menu not closing

Tags: jquery

I made a dropdown menu, the first item menu you click on for the sub-menu to appear and any sub-menus within that show/hide on hover/hover off. The only problem I'm having is I want the main navigation to close on clicking anywhere on the document.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".mainNav ul li").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).find("> ul").css({ "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible", "top": "30px" });
            });
        jQuery(".sub-menu li").mouseover(function () {
            jQuery(this).find("> ul").css({ "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible", "top": "30px" });
        });
        jQuery('.sub-menu li').mouseout(function () {
            jQuery(this).find("> ul").css({ "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden", "top": "35px"});
        });});

//the code i tried below
jQuery('document').click(function () {
        jQuery(.mainNav ul li ).find("> ul").css({ "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden", "top": "35px"});
    });});

    });
```

I assume the two click events are conflicting, but I'm not too sure familiar with how to handle it.

I messed around and the drop down closes if for example I change the click event onto a 'h1' element, which is right below it. I then changed it to .container and the sub menu doesn't even come up at all.

Comment: Shouldn't `jQuery(.mainNav ul li )` be `jQuery('.mainNav ul li' )`

Comment: Ah yes I typed that in freehand, not copy/paste. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or `:not`

```
jQuery(document).not(".mainNav ul").click(function () {
    jQuery(".mainNav ul li").find("> ul").css({ "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden", "top": "35px"});
});});
```

You're missing some parenthesis in the selector which I added as well

You also have an extra set of `});` and your `document` click function is not inside of the ready function. Try putting it inside of the ready function, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/WD5jV/) by removing the `});` after the `mouseout`

On a side note you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` if you'd like

**Edit**

I got it to work [in my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WD5jV/1/) using `:not` and `on("click",...` Try the the full jQuery if just this snippet doesn't work

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ":not(.mainNav ul, .mainNav ul *)", function () {
    jQuery(".mainNav ul li").find("> ul").css({
        "opacity": "0",
            "visibility": "hidden",
            "top": "35px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Would it make any difference that this is for a wordpress theme, maybe that's why it's not wroking? I read somewhere that I should use jQuery instead of $ when working with wordpress, maybe that was an old article? Still doesn't work with the quotes removed, damn.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, no

Comment: The sub-menu doesn't appear at all now

Comment: Updated again, see if it helps

Comment: Okay, using the code in the jsfiddle made it work. Still no idea what I was doing wrong haha. Thanks alot!

Comment: I think the main difference is using `:not` instead of `.not()`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
jQuery(document).not('.mainNav ul').click(function () {
//-----^------^-------you have to remove quotes here.
```